# How to receive multiple emitted parameters with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I see the socket.io cheat sheet but it doesn't explain how to receive multiple data.

Client example:

```
socket.emit('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
```

Server Example:

```
socket.on('foo', (msg) => {
    console.log('message: ' + msg); //output is "message: bar"
});
```

How do I obtain baz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying the arguments in your listener works,

```
socket.on('foo', (msg1, ms2) => {
    console.log('message1: ' + msg1); 
    console.log('message2: ' + msg2);
});
```